# How to place a code snippet using minted inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: minted, tcolorbox

This is a piece of my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable=true]
\centering
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
\inputminted{gnuplot}{script.txt}
\end{tcolorbox}  
\end{document}
```

[This](http://textuploader.com/nymx) is the `script.txt` file:

This is how the output looks like:

[image: The tcolorbox spans across pages, but the minted code is not 'inside' it]

I am trying to fit the minted code in the tcolorbox, such that the code also spans across pages. Can someone guide me in the right way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Sure, I will try my best to. It's not tedious to me, but I am using a template for my document and am building it up slowly by looking into the posts on TeX.SX, as I am a complete beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: @jsp99 but we have no access to `script.txt`, so we cannot reproduce the problem. Either provide the file or provide some dummy replacement contents allowing us to reproduce the proble. Also, your code is missing the document class that you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the cause of the problem. Your use of `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment` seems to make the minted code unbreakable. If you omit this (and thereby also omit centering), your code is breakable:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{script.txt}
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
Bla bla bla bla bla.
Blub blub blub.
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\rule{1pt}{14cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced]
%\centering
%\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
\inputminted{gnuplot}{script.txt}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

You get the same result, if you use the `minted` library of `tcolorbox` and its `\tcbinputlisting` command instead of putting `\inputminted` into a `tcolorbox`.

With your provided `script.txt` plus setting `minted options={breaklines}` for line breaking, this gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\tcbinputlisting{
  listing file=script.txt,
  minted language=gnuplot,
  minted options={breaklines},% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
  breakable,enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
  listing only
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have many gnuplot inputs, you can wrap all settings into a new macro using `\newcommand` or `\newtcbinputlisting` (from `tcolorbox`).

For example, create a new macro `\gnuplotinput` like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,minted}

\newtcbinputlisting{\gnuplotinput}[2][]{%
  listing file={#2},
  minted language=gnuplot,
  minted options={breaklines},% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
  breakable,enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
  listing only,#1
}

\begin{document}

\gnuplotinput{script.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that almost solved the problem. But my code lines are long (I updated my question with the script.txt file) and they don't wrap at the right boundary of tcolorbox. Can you suggest a solution for that as well?

Comment: @jsp99 Yes, the recent version of `minted` supports line breaks. I have updated my answer in this way.