# How to use the latest minted package in overleaf?

Tags: packages, minted, overleaf

I am working on a document in [**overleaf**](https://www.overleaf.com/). I am using the `minted` package to place code in my document. I need to use the `breaklines` option of the `minted` package which only the latest version of the package seems to support. I get the following error when I use the `breaklines` option inside `tcbinputlisting`:

```
Package keyval Error: breaklines undefined. 
See the keyval package documentation for explanation. 
Type H <return> for immediate help. ... 

l.412 }
```

This question is a sort of sequel to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250538/how-to-place-a-code-snippet-using-minted-inside-a-tcolorbox/250614#250614) solved question. This is the code that is causing the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\tcbinputlisting{
 listing file=script.txt,
 minted language=gnuplot,
 minted options={breaklines},% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
 breakable,enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
 listing only
}

\end{document}
```

I have deduced from the situation that this is most likely a problem with the version of the `minted` package.

How can I use the latest version of `minted` in *overleaf* and avoid the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [per the FAQ](https://www.overleaf.com/help/30-what-packages-do-you-support), the currently installed version (as of this writing) is TeX Live 2014, which does not include the up to date version of minted.

The FAQ also says to contact the Overleaf team with specific package requirements.

However, an easier option is to just add the [`minted.sty` file version 2.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gpoore/minted/master/source/minted.sty) to your Overleaf project. Then this file will be used instead of the system installed `minted.sty`. I’ve verified that this works.