# Grade table too long within exam document class

Tags: exam, gradetable

I'm creating my own exam paper and I have 15 different questions. Using the code

```
\gradetable[h][questions]
```

I'm getting a grade table. However as I have so many questions the table it too big

[image]

I'm trying to split the table in half and put them under each other but I cant get any code to work.

When I have been using the command

\begin{center}

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.25in}

\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]

\end{center}

It just keeps on coming up with a error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compliable tex code resulting in your shown screenshot.

Comment: Try `\noindent\gradetable[h][questions]`.

Comment: If a vertical table is ok try `\gradetable[v][questions]`

Comment: `\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]`

you can replace 2 by any numbre

Comment: Yous should always provide A so called **MWE** (minimal working example) a code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and that reproduces the issue you are facing. This  helps who try to help you   to better understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As mentionned in the `exam` *class* manual:**

> If you want to print a horizontal grading table but the table would be too large for the page,
>   you can print a grading table with multiple rows by giving the command:
>          `\multirowgradetable{numrows}[questions or pages]`

**The MWE**

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
{
\question[\i]

a nice question

\begin{solution}
my solution
\end{solution}
}



\end{questions}

\multirowgradetable{2}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i have tried the multirow command but it just comes up with a error or some reason. i have been just tried the code posted above but still a error
using the code
\begin{center}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0.25in}
\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]
\end{center}
just keeps giving a error

Comment: @JettieBaker `\multirowgradetable` command is a new feature in the `exam` class. May be you should update your TeX installation!

Comment: Im using overleaf.com for my latex but i have copied and pasted your code but it comes up with the same error.

Comment: @JettieBaker  the TeX distribution in overleaf is not updated. I have tried the code with TeXlive 2018 and it works perfectly. Try to download the latest `exam` class from ctan and add it to your project. Take a look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250730/how-to-use-the-latest-minted-package-in-overleaf)

Comment: @JettieBaker download the [exam package](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) and upload the `exam.cls` file to your project in overleaf

Comment: thank you so much i have got it to all work now

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer of [Hafid Boukhoulda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/91130/hafid-boukhoulda) (using his code), you can adjust the cell width of gradetable with `\cellwidth` command (exam class manual, p.89).

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % For testing the gradetable is in frame?
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\foreach \i in {1,...,15}
{
\question[\i]
a nice question
}
\end{questions}

\cellwidth{0.3cm}

\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i dont want to squish the table i just want to split it but for some reason its just not working